# View doesn't update another view in wpf mvvm application

Tags: c#, wpf, unity-container, prism

I'm working on a wpf application. I have a shell which has a region. And I have two views, one is for editing person object and the other one is for listing all personnel (an observable collection). Two views are working correctly.

Whenever I use personnel list view and update entity and switch to person view I see the updated entity. After changing the entity in person view and returning  to personnel view again it doesn't update the view.  (I am using prism and unity.) I stuck.

Thanks in advance.

//My person class

```
public class Personel : ModelBase, IPerson
{
    [Key]
    public int PersonelId { get; set; }

    public string Ad { get; set; }

    public int CinsiyetId { get; set; }

    public DateTime DogumTarihi { get; set; }

    public string DogumYeri { get; set; }

    public string Foto { get; set; }

    public string IkinciAd { get; set; }

    public int SaglikDurumId { get; set; }

    public string SaglikSorun { get; set; }

    public string Soyad { get; set; }

    public int TahsilId { get; set; }

    public long TCKN { get; set; }

    public string BabaAdi { get; set; }

    public string AnneAdi { get; set; }

    public int NüfusIlId { get; set; }//+

    public string NüfusIlce { get; set; }

    public string Mahalle { get; set; }

    public int CiltNo { get; set; }

    public int AileSiraNo { get; set; }

    public int SiraNo { get; set; }

    public bool MedeniHal { get; set; }

    public DateTime EvlilikTarih { get; set; }

    public int TelefonAsil { get; set; }

    public int TelefonYedek { get; set; }

    public int TelefonEv { get; set; }

    //public string Adres { get; set; }

    //public int IsActive { get; set; }

    //public string Sicil { get; set; }

    public int Boy { get; set; }

    public int Kilo { get; set; }

    public int KanGrubuId { get; set; }//+

    public bool Sigara { get; set; }

    public int YabanciDilId { get; set; }//+

    public int YabanciDilDurumId { get; set; }//+

}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Nehir.YBS.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
        prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
        Title="{Binding Title}" Height="700" Width="1280" ShowInTaskbar="False" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="Maximized">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.15*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.85*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TreeView Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Lists">
                <Hyperlink Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" CommandParameter="Personel">Personnel List</Hyperlink>                
            </TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Editing">
                <Hyperlink  Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" CommandParameter="PersonelInfo">Personnel</Hyperlink>                
            </TreeViewItem>
        </TreeView>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="ContentRegion"  VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        private string _title = "Prism Unity Application";
        public string Title
        {
            get { return _title; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _title, value); }
        }

        private readonly IRegionManager regionManager;

        public DelegateCommand<string> NavigateCommand { get; set; }

        public MainWindowViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager)
        {
            this.regionManager = regionManager;
            NavigateCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(Navigate);
        }

        private void Navigate(string uri)
        {
            this.regionManager.RequestNavigate("ContentRegion", uri);
        }
    }
```

Personel.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="Nehir.YBS.Views.Personel"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Nehir.YBS.Views"
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid x:Name="personelDataGrid" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding PersonelList,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" Margin="0,0,280,0">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="PersonelId" Binding="{Binding PersonelId, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ad" Binding="{Binding Ad, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ad2" Binding="{Binding IkinciAd, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Soyad" Binding="{Binding Soyad, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Doğum Tarihi">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding DogumTarihi, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Button Content="Kaydet" Grid.Row="1" Command="{Binding UpdateCommand}" Width="75" Height="35" Margin="15,0,15,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

PersonelViewModel.cs

```
public class PersonelViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        Repository<Personel, YBSDbContext> repo = new Repository<Personel, YBSDbContext>(new YBSDbContext());

        private ObservableCollection<Personel> personelList;

        public ObservableCollection<Personel> PersonelList
        {
            get { return personelList; }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref personelList, value);
            }
        }

        public PersonelViewModel()
        {
            UpdateCommand = new DelegateCommand(Execute, CanExecute);
            PersonelList = new ObservableCollection<Personel>(repo.GetAll());
        }

        private bool CanExecute()
        {
            if (PersonelList is ObservableCollection<Personel>)
            {
                return true;    
            }
            return false;
        }

        private void Execute()
        {
            repo.Save();
        }

        public DelegateCommand UpdateCommand { get; set; }
    }
```

PersoonelInfo.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="Nehir.YBS.Views.PersonelInfo"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"             
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
             VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.95*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.05*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Expander x:Name="temel" Header="Personel Kişisel Bilgileri" MinWidth="1000" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"  Width="1000">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0,15*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0,35*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0,15*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0,35*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding PersonelInfo.PersonelId, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding PersonelInfo.Ad, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding PersonelInfo.IkinciAd, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding PersonelInfo.Soyad, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding PersonelInfo.DogumTarihi, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding PersonelInfo.DogumYeri, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding PersonelInfo.TCKN, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding PersonelInfo.Foto, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding PersonelInfo.AnneAdi, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding PersonelInfo.BabaAdi, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding PersonelInfo.MedeniHal, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="10" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding PersonelInfo.EvlilikTarih, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="11" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="PersonelId" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Ad" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="IkinciAd" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Soyad" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="DogumTarihi" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="DogumYeri" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="TCKN" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Foto" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="AnneAdi" Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="BabaAdi" Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="MedeniHal" Grid.Row="10" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="EvlilikTarihi" Grid.Row="11" Grid.Column="0"/>
                </Grid>
            </Expander>
            <Expander x:Name="egitim_saglik"  Header="Eğitim/Sağlık Bilgileri" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5" Width="1000">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0,15*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0,35*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0,15*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0,35*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding PersonelInfo.SaglikDurumId, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding PersonelInfo.SaglikSorun, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding PersonelInfo.Boy, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding PersonelInfo.Kilo, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding PersonelInfo.KanGrubuId, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding PersonelInfo.Sigara, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Sağlık Durumu" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Sağlık Sorunu" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Boy" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Kilo" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Kan Grubu" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Sigara" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding PersonelInfo.TahsilId, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding PersonelInfo.YabanciDilId, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding PersonelInfo.YabanciDilDurumId, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="TahsilId" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="YabanciDilId" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="YabanciDilDurumId" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"/>
                </Grid>
            </Expander>
            <Expander x:Name="nufus_iletisim"  Header="Nüfus ve İletişim Bilgileri" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5" Width="1000">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0,15*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0,35*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0,15*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0,35*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding PersonelInfo.NüfusIlId, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding PersonelInfo.NüfusIlce, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding PersonelInfo.Mahalle, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding PersonelInfo.CiltNo, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding PersonelInfo.AileSiraNo, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding PersonelInfo.SiraNo, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Nüfus İl" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Nüfus İlçe" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Mahalle" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Cilt No" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Aile Sıra No" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Sıra No" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding PersonelInfo.TelefonAsil, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding PersonelInfo.TelefonYedek, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding PersonelInfo.TelefonEv, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding PersonelInfo.Adres, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="3"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Telefon" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Telefon Yedek" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Telefon Ev" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Adres" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="2"/>
                </Grid>
            </Expander>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="Kaydet" Command="{Binding UpdateCommand}" Width="75" Margin="15,0,15,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

PersonelInfoViewModel.cs

```
public class PersonelInfoViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        Repository<Personel, YBSDbContext> repo = new Repository<Personel, YBSDbContext>(new YBSDbContext());

    private Personel personelInfo;

    public Personel PersonelInfo
    {
        get { return personelInfo; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref personelInfo, value);
        }
    }



public PersonelInfoViewModel()

{
    UpdateCommand = new DelegateCommand(Execute,CanExecute);
    personelInfo = repo.FindBy(p => p.TCKN == 11111111111).Single();//for example
}

private bool CanExecute()
{
    return PersonelInfo is Personel;
}

private void Execute()
{
    repo.Save();   
}

public DelegateCommand UpdateCommand { get; set; }
```

Comment: 1.  What does your Person class look like?  2.  What does your xaml look like that displays the content that you want to be updated?  3.  what does your code that is actually modifying the person object look like?  Use an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) if you think including all that will take up too much space.

Comment: do you have sample code, can't tell much without looking at the code

Comment: Best guess is you are creating a new object for the PersonView out of an object from the PersonalListView. So updating via PersonalListView works fine, but updating from PersonView does not because the changes are not persisted back tot he PersonalListView copy of the object model.

Comment: I will add my sample code soon. Sorry.

Comment: One of my objects is a observable collection of person and the other is a single object of person

Comment: you added the wrong tag

Answer (score 0):

I currently don't have enough information to know for sure, but when I'm faced with an issue like the one you're describing, I'd check the following things:

- Make sure `OnPropertyChanged` is Getting called for the properties that you want updated.  Setting the property with `BindableBase.SetProperty` should cover this for you.
- Make sure that your Xaml elements are properly bound to the property that you're updating.  Make sure that the [Binding.Mode Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.mode(v=vs.110).aspx) is not set to something that would prevent the control from being updated.

Comment: My viewmodels are inherit from BindableBase. Binding mode is two way and update source trigger is setted to propertychanged.

Answer (score 0):

> Best guess is you are creating a new object for the PersonView out of
>   an object from the PersonalListView. So updating via PersonalListView
>   works fine, but updating from PersonView does not because the changes
>   are not persisted back tot he PersonalListView copy of the object
>   model. – Rachel

After reading Rachel comment. I realized, I am waiting two different object in two different view that refers same entity(but totally different objects) to update each other. They can only update their own UI and database. They can't notify changes in my approach. So I create single repository object which is shared in all application wide and use it every time I need.

//App.xaml.cs

```
public partial class App : Application
    {
        public static Repository<Personel, YBSDbContext> repo = new Repository<Personel, YBSDbContext>(new YBSDbContext());

        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);

            var bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();
            bootstrapper.Run();
        }
    }
```

And one of my views that uses app-wide repository object.

```
public class PersonelInfoViewModel : BindableBase
{
    Repository<Personel, YBSDbContext> repo = App.repo;
```

I am not sure that this is a good way. But it solved my problem, at least for now. I will be happy hearing your comments.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you will have too implement on property change on all the properties defined in Personel class. Right now you just have default getter setter property.

Since the edit you are doing is a property level your view wont update to change until you have Property Change implemented.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Using INotifyPropertyChanged  interface didn't solve my problem. Beacuse the collection which populates the datagrid in PersonViewModel and the Personel object which populates the PersonInfoViewModel are two seperate object and they don't notify each other.  I handled the situation by using my own answer. Thanks...